# CS50's pset3 Tideman... my lock function doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, cs50

I've been trying to solve an issue I have with the lock_pairs function. I used recursion to validate if we have a path that follows a cycle (basically, follow the losers path to see if it won against another candidate and checking if we get back to the origin point, effectively forming a cycle).

But I have an issue since it returns an error when using check50 to validate my solution, and I'm way too lost to even think what is wrong, I feel I've checked everything and still it doesn't work.

This is the error from check50:

```
:( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
```

Here's the code:

```
    // To be used in lock_pairs to avoid cycles, true means cycles, false means we good
bool check_cycles(int loser_ind, int winner_ind)
{
    // Base case, if the loser path returns to the winner, we have a circle
    if (loser_ind == winner_ind)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (locked[loser_ind][i]) // If the loser has an edge over another candidate, i.e, if the loser candidate won against another candidate
        {
            return check_cycles(i, winner_ind); // We'll check if that other candidate that lost has a winning path to another candidate
        }
    }

    return false;

}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // Let's loop on all pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        // If we didn't created a cycle, we'll register the lock
        if (!check_cycles(pairs[i].loser, pairs[i].winner))
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true; // It means the i-th pair winner candidate won over i-th pair losing candidate
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: You may consider locking the loser index, so the winner will have no locks at the end. Your cycle check simply needs to be called on the last lock iteration. (before that, there is no possibility of a cycle). When placing locks, if you initialize an array of `int` with `pair_count`elements all zero at the beginning and then set the value at `array[pairs[i].loser] = 1` with each edge locked, you can simply check if only one index remains zero and if that corresponds to the index of the next lock to place -- don't place it. (at least that worked out for all tests in PSET3)

Comment: Thanks!! Actually this helped me to understand better the exercise

Comment: Glad it helped. If you are still stuck, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe changing

```
return check_cycles(i, winner_ind);
```

to

```
if (check_cycles(i, winner_ind)){
    return true;
}
```

would fix it

Comment: "return check_cycles(i, winner_ind);" ends the for loop and return to the previous iteration of check_cycles, without checking all "i, winner_ind" pairs, just the first, while "if (check_cycles(i, winner_ind)){
    return true;
}" only stops the loop and this iteration of the function when a cycle is found

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood it now